# How to set team-wide ReSharper and code formatting settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-8.0

We would like to have common team-wide editor settings in Visual Studio 2012. We use ReSharper.

Is there any way for all team members to have Visual Studio editor settings that they can import from a central fileshare?

**What I have tried**

ReSharper describes how to have shared settings in the tutorial [Managing and Sharing Options](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Configuring_ReSharper__Sharing_Configuration_Options.html). This didn't seem to work on my PC (the settings didn't seem to import or export properly). In addition, ReSharper does not appear to control things like tabs, so we are wondering how to import editor settings for Visual Studio as well. Is it possible to have a single unified solution that allows a team to share editor settings?

Comment: Which version of ReSharper are you using?

Comment: I am using ReSharper v8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have looked at using the import and export settings in resharper to keep settings consistent across the teams however this was unfavourable as you had to import settings on each machine for each user account. For example if you login as a different user on the same machine which is already configured then you would have to reimport the settings.

### Team Shared settings

In the end I opted for the Team Shared settings which stores the settings in your source control repository (file will be something like `<solution name>.dotSettings`. When you edit settings in ReSharper you will need to remember to save them to Team Settings.

[image]

You can also store File and Live templates in the solution as well. These will store in the dotSettings file as well.

[image]

### Override

This will not enforce the same settings as developers can override on a per user bases by storing personal settings on their machine.

### Persisting

As I mentioned before if you do not include the files generated by ReSharper in Source Control the settings will not be persisted across the team. Do not include the `<solution name>.dotsettings.user` as these are user specific settings and should not be included.

### Multiple projects

If you want to have the same settings across multiple projects you will need to either copy the settings files across and rename the file name to match the name of the solution or import them. I think this works better than enforcing exactly the same settings across all teams as it allows each team to decide how they want to work.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A little additional hint. You can also use separate settings per project if you create `<projectname>.DotSetting` file. However you have no UI to do it. It is usefull e.g. to allow underscores in unit test method names only.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this was possible!

Answer (score 3):

All the `.DotSettings` files can be distributed as an extension for ReSharper.

You can publish an extension to the official NuGet feed from JetBrains, to your private NuGet server or even to the shared folder. The obvious benefit is that you don't have to care about upgrading settings on every developer's PC (it will be detected automatically by ReSharper itself).

The extension is a regular NuGet package. So what you need is:

1. Export settings to the file using Manage Options dialog
2. Write the `.nuspec` file
3. Create a .nupkg file using nuget.exe
4. Place the package to the feed
5. Configure R# to use your new feed

I have [a blog post with a step-by-step manual](http://asizikov.github.io/2015/07/05/sharing-resharper-settings/).

Comment: I've had luck in the past following the process outlined in your blog, thanks for that. I'm hoping you might have an insight in a problem I'm currently encountering. In my last shop we used ProGet for publishing our internal NuGet packages. This is how I shared the R# settings. At the new shop they share NuGet packages on a network file share. I've created a folder for extensions, put my nupkg there, and set my R# Extension Manager to use that share as a source - but it doesn't find my package. I'm using R# 9.2. Have you seen file shares work? Is there a trick?

Comment: no, there is no trick, First of all, make sure that package has "." in a name, wave version is correct (it's 3.0 for R#9.2 as far as I remember) and content is stored in a correct folder (DotFiles\Extensions\YourPackage.Name\settings). Also, if the version of your package is not stable (see SemVer as a reference) allow R# to use prerelease packages.

Comment: Using the correct Wave version fixed my issue. Thanks a bunch!